# When i run this code for aco i got error Uniform can not be resolved to a type

Tags: java, uniform

Here the code..this shows error while using uniform that uniform can not be resolved to a type.

```
private Uniform uniform;

    private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);

    private final ExecutorCompletionService<WalkedWay> agentCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<WalkedWay>(
                    threadPool);

    final double[][] matrix;
    final double[][] invertedMatrix;
    private final double[][] pheromones;
    private final Object[][] mutexes;

    public AntColonyOptimization() throws IOException {
            // read the matrix
            matrix = readMatrixFromFile();
            invertedMatrix = invertMatrix();
            pheromones = initializePheromones();
            mutexes = initializeMutexObjects();
            // (double min, double max, int seed)
            uniform = new Uniform(0, matrix.length - 1, (int) System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
```

Comment: the class name is Uniform and not uniform in the first line

Comment: I have changed it..but issue is same.

Comment: you need to `import` the package containing the `uniform` class.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your declaration part

```
private Uniform uniform ;
```

Comment: Where is the Uniform class ? You need to import this class